# How to get rid of HTML tags

Tags: html, drupal

I am a little stuck and need help. So it goes like this. I have a site where the count of comments on a particular article comes from comment module. the HTML tag on it is displayed which looks something this `(<em>1</em>)`. I have recently upgraded my site 5 to 6. Everything else works fine apart from this.
Please Help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please put some more light on your question, it seems its not clear.

Comment: your reference (1) seems not to be working...

Comment: Clarify the question a bit .. It is hard to assume .. Piece of the code is most welcome ..

Comment: You haven't actually asked anything, do you want to change the markup, or what is it you need help for.

Comment: Yes, the actual problem is very unclear. Do you want to get rid of the HTML (or change it) or is the problem that the HTML is actually output to the browser (as though it were being escaped out)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function to remove HTML from string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get rid of `<em>1</em>`:
`\<em([^>]*)\>(\d[^>]*)\</(em[^>]*)\>` -> removes all bracketed text, containing numbers.

And if this is clumsy, shh, I only learnt regexes yesterday.

Comment: Parsing html with regexes... this is folklore now: don't do it! The Whatif flood is coming. What if the brackets contain an open tag and not the closing tag? What if there is an unrelated bracket containing a number? * matches 0 or more, so you would also match anything in brackets without a digit. Matching is also greedy, so an open bracket near the beginning of the document and a close near the end would be matched, and the whole doc goes. Etc etc. Search for 'regex html' on SO to see the horror.

Comment: I've seen bobince's cry for help. I use lxml to parse my trees. However, I will continue to regexes to my heart's content. Perhaps to my own detriment, but at least I'll learn something huh XD.